# How to recover data from a state instantly?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I start using NgRx and am a little lost to access the data contained in the State.
I searched several hours before asking my question because I did not really find an answer.

When using NgRx to display the data on a list, it's fabulous.
I wanted to go more using NgRx to group the settings of my application with my SettingsState.

I would like to put particular in my SettingsState:
- the base URL for API requests,
- the number of lines to display in a list: important during API requests to limit the data to be retrieved.
- ...

**When I'm in an Effect, how can I directly retrieve my important parameters to launch my API requests?**

I understood that to recover the data, it is necessary to use the "selectors" to obtain an "Observable" which will allow me to be informed as soon as a change will arrive.

However, here I want the values ​​now without waiting to launch my API requests.
How can I do ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, you should use **selectors** to access Data from your store. You can use selectors in components, but also in effects.

Look at this example effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class ElementEffects {
constructor (private store: Store<any>, private apiService: ApiService) {}

      @Effect()
      public yourEffect: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<yourActionClass>(ActionsEnum.YOUR_ACTION),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectSomethingFromTheStore))),
        concatMap(([action, selectedDateFromTheStore]) => this.apiService.doBackendCall(selectedDateFromTheStore, action.payload).pipe(
          map(([resultFromTheBackendCall, selectedDateFromTheStore]) => {
            // Do Stuff
          },
          catchError((error) => of(new FailureAction(error)))
          )
        ),
      );
}
```

The "withLatestFrom" allows you to **add another observable** to your chain. You will have the result instantly and you can use it.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html